# How to make IDEA know about $ import aliases in Svelte?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, svelte

[image]

I want IDEA to recognize aliases in Svelte as correct syntax and provide completion. How do I do that? The code compiles and works fine.

Comment: Which IDEA version do you use?

Comment: You'll need the svelte plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12375-svelte.
I see they delivered a new version just yesterday. Is it the one you're using ? They don't provide changelogs so we don't really know what's in there. The only thing I know is they would have a working version before the end of 2023.
As far as I love IDEA, I am using VSCode until they have a real support :)